# Java Class that can be used to represent null and absent differently

Tags: java, guava

I am wondering if there is a ready made Java class that can be used similarly with Guava's Optional but treats null and absent differently.

I have use case that requires to pass a method parameter with String value, null value or absent (does not provide anything). Null is a purely valid value and carries special meaning.

I tried to use Guava's Optional but found that it cannot differentiate null and absent. Passwing null to Optional means absent.

I am wondering if there is a ready made Java utility that can be used for my usecase: It can carry a value, null value or no value (absent).

many thanks

Comment: If you didn't have such a class, how would you implement it? What does _absent_ mean?

Comment: absent is the value is not specified. For example, if you want to use the value as the search parameter of DB, null value means a particualr value is null, absent means I don't care about this value, anything will match.

Answer (score 1):

The java language can do it: Use a token object to represent "absent".

Say it's a String type:

```
private static final String ABSENT = new String(""); // not interned

private String attribute = ABSENT;

public boolean attributeIsSet() {
    return attribute == ABSENT; // identity comparison
}

public String getAttribute() {
    if (attributeIsSet())
        return attribute;
    throw new IllegalStateException(); // or whatever
}
```

This allows `null` to be a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Optional`.

`Optional` is you know that something is either present or not. Add the meaning null to `Optional` by returning... `null`.

```
Optional<A> a = Optional.of(new A()); // We know that A is present.
Optional<B> b = Optional.absent();    // We know that B is absent.
Optional<C> c = null;                 // We don't know if C is present or absent.
```

Working with `null` isn't bad: it's error-prone. So be careful, document properly what you want to do and how `null` should be interpreted.

Comment: I upvoted this but changed my mind.  I can't undo my upvote without downvoting instead so I feel compelled to comment.  The OP wants a second kind of "not there".  Your suggestion will work, but it's not much better than using null for a value with only one kind of "not there" instead of Optional.  It's not a ready-made class that provides the same benefits for 2 not-theres as Optional does for 1 not-there.

Comment: I understand your point of view and, by all means, downvote if you no longer feel this is needed. I based my answer on the philosophy behind http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained . It's not bad to use `null` if you use it consciously of what it means and if people using your code know what it means. Of course, as I said, it's error prone and using a token object is probably better (or a specific `Optional`-like wrapper). But are we ready to use `Optional<Optional<Object>>` for the sake of not using `null`?

Comment: Please don't read this like I'm giving advice to you Olivier...  The quoted philosophy is perfect: "you have to actively unwrap the Optional and address that case".  If the Optional can be null, that advantage is gone.  Also, an Optional Optional emits all sorts of bad odor.  That's going way too far down the "but I don't want to write my own classes!" path.  Write your own class that does what you want.  Optional doesn't fit.  Using Optional for this is like using HashMap instead of a class.  I stand by my upvote for you though, because your solution works.  No one should get stuck on this.

Comment: I have to say, the notion of letting an `Optional` be `@Nullable` is about the clearest anti-pattern I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

> Null ... carries special meaning.

Whenever you find yourself saying this, it should be [a red flag](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) that your design merits re-thinking, as `null` by definition carries no meaning.  Lets step back and look at your requirements (feel free to update the question with better descriptions of your intent if this is inaccurate):

- Absence: Indicates we've nothing to do here at all
- `null`: Indicates a "special value", such as `DEFAULT` or `FALLBACK`, which should be handled specially
- Value: A "normal" value, including the empty string, that can be handled directly

This is not an unusual problem, (particularly when working with nullable database columns, as I think you are) and `Optional` can quite successfully represent this, but we need to structure it better.

While we can't avoid `NULL`s in databases, we can strive to restrict their scope to the minimal code surrounding our database access behavior, and expose it no further than that.  We conceptually do this by converting nullable fields to `Optional`s, as you know.  So `col VARCHAR NULL` should always be converted into Java as an `Optional<String> col` as soon as possible.

But now we need to represent the absence case, such as when we `SELECT col FROM table LIMIT 1` and get nothing back from our query.  Obviously, this should be handled differently than if we get back a `NULL`.

We have a couple of choices, but they all boil down to wrapping our `Optional<String>` in another layer somehow.

In many cases you can simply use a `List` or other `Collection`.  By passing back a non-null collection we can generally handle the absent case trivially, as our code will simply not enter whatever loop would otherwise process the data if the `List` is empty.  So `List<Optional<String>>` is one option.

If that's not possible, and you really want to limit the behavior to one-or-none, such as in the `LIMIT 1` example above, simply wrap it in another `Optional`, i.e. `Optional<Optional<String>>`.  This clearly conveys the difference between absence of a result, and absence of a value in a type-safe manner.

A little more work, but even better is to properly represent this structure in its own class (any time you have generics inside generics, consider creating a proper holding class), since really what we're talking about is a optional piece of data, which may itself contain an optional piece of data.

```
public class Row {
  private final Optional<String> col;
  public Row(@Nullable String col) {
    this.col = Optional.fromNullable(col);
  }
  public Optional<String> getCol() {
    return col;
  }
}
```

Then you pass around `Optional<Row>` objects, which very clearly either exists or doesn't, and either contain a result, or not.  All type-safe, and no `null`s needed.

---

tl;dr: This can be rationally represented with `Optional<Optional<String>>`, or see above for additional suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't an empty String ("") the same as 'no value' for a string?  Obviously this wouldn't work for numbers, but you're specifically talking about a String.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really mean the value is absent.

Comment: Depending on the use case `""` could mean "no value" or it could be a meaningful value.  Since `""` is ambiguous in similar ways to `null`, it's also generally a poor pattern to use `""` to represent some sort of sentinel value.  It's slightly better, in that at least you won't get NPEs, but it should still be avoided where possible.